# How to get the child of an element using an event trigger and a custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you can help me with my problem.
Here's my sample code

```
<input type="checkbox" data-attr="getAllChoices" />

<div id="parent">

     <div id="child1">
         <input type="checkbox" value="3"/>Choice A
     </div>

     <div id="child2">
         <input type="checkbox" value="5"/>Choice B
     </div>

     <div id="child3">
         <input type="checkbox" value="6"/>Choice C
     </div>

</div>
```

Scenario:

If if the user check the checkbox, all choices should be check also. The date-attr should be use for comparing. If it has a value it will call the child of the parent (checkboxes) and check it all.

So far in my js I have this. But I don't have an idea how to call the other checkboxes.The only thing that I know is call the checkboxes by accessing the child div.

```
$("input[data-attr='checkAll']").on('change',function(){
     //no idea. . . . . 
});
```

By the way I am using jquery 1.5

Comment: what are you trying to do with data-attr="getAllChoices" in your checkbox?

Comment: use this as a validation. If it has a value, check all the checkboxes.

Comment: @RochelleCanale how is it different from your previous question?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tan5y/1/

Comment: I need to access from parent div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the `data-check` attribute. So try using the `data-attr` attribute:

```
$("input[data-attr='getAllChoices']").bind('change',function(){
      $('#parent').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

If you want to avoid the use of `attr()` for the checked property, you can iterate over the checkboxes manually:

```
$("input[data-attr='getAllChoices']").bind('change',function(){
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    $('#parent').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, val){
        val.checked = isChecked;
    });
});
```

Comment: They said they are using Jquery 1.5 so they have to use `.attr('checked','checked')` instead of .prop

Comment: I think you have to iterate through the divs named 'child' to get what the questioner is trying to achieve.

Comment: @MrCode may need to change to `bind` instead of `on`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, uses `change` method in jQuery 1.5:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('input[data-attr="checkAll"]').change(function () {
            $('#parent').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
            //OR
            // $('#parent input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);
     });
});
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PYRyN/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("input[data-attr='getAllChoices']").bind('change', function () {
    $('#parent input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', this.checked)
});
```